# ggforest not showing Refernce group for one of the variables

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have a dataframe `df1` (its `dput` is placed at the bottom to save space), and I am running the DFS analysis as follows:

```
require(survival)
require(survminer)
require(ggplot2)

cox_fit <- coxph(Surv(DFS,Relapsed) ~ Gender + Stage + MSI, data=df1)     
ggforest(cox_fit, data = df1, refLabel = "Reference Group")
```

[image: forest plot]
You can see that `Gender` and `MSI` variables have one level shown as "Reference Group", as expected - but `Stage` variable does not have it, and I don't understand why. When I just print `cox_fit` object, it looks fine with all three variables:

```
cox_fit 
# Call:
#   coxph(formula = Surv(DFS, Relapsed) ~ Gender + Stage + MSI, data = df1)
# 
# coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z        p
# GenderMale 0.7952    2.2149   0.2916 2.727  0.00639
# StageIII   1.8824    6.5693   0.4342 4.335 1.46e-05
# MSIMSI-Hi  0.4551    1.5763   0.3677 1.238  0.21579
# 
# Likelihood ratio test=35.43  on 3 df, p=9.872e-08
# n= 337, number of events= 57
```

I don't understand what's special about `Stage` variable that makes it look weird on the forest plot.

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(
    DFS = c(474,280,439,468,155,390,484,432,254,453,375,426,540,236,396,315,255,444,336,414,394,362,376,280,366,346,163,363,308,297,253,288,261,111,288,339,274,282,136,213,85,113,35,76,67,75,28,136,1339,1238,1324,117,75,1191,1234,1222,1320,1162,651,1234,1224,270,1233,1266,1071,1149,1159,1140,1224,1071,1174,1056,561,1022,315,1110,1081,1183,1166,1085,1171,689,86,1048,1087,527,539,1199,1106,1102,1113,1108,870,228,1019,89,1056,1140,1063,1082,193,1030,777,231,137,394,1079,408,994,100,805,978,1022,518,36,516,634,930,934,847,904,345,817,852,342,97,663,1031,888,349,684,188,431,114,994,922,1030,743,935,888,287,915,613,927,2,137,842,793,770,94,160,884,892,711,679,676,409,924,806,887,978,855,189,801,518,843,807,944,657,775,988,891,756,1013,892,404,883,738,853,161,496,241,870,704,97,677,865,862,650,722,873,737,851,816,891,603,726,65,833,789,93,787,812,611,505,715,833,756,707,710,149,828,830,678,371,78,210,874,658,564,705,734,648,729,223,440,752,789,863,222,563,540,794,160,651,792,578,781,586,351,623,487,442,807,673,716,369,735,301,255,729,514,701,116,160,654,226,700,751,672,52,728,423,766,627,217,784,161,607,357,606,722,152,631,365,416,590,28,573,590,656,114,166,420,196,538,693,623,676,65,725,626,646,627,681,8,680,65,655,157,613,620,693,153,630,147,645,232,591,494,646,595,291,604,629,424,251,499,513,424,487,592,555,570,543,491,43,501,563,558,469,645,511,453,475,427,314),
    Relapsed = c(T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,F,F,T,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,T,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T),
    Gender = structure(
      c(2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2),
      levels = c("Female","Male"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    Stage = structure(
c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2),
      levels = c("II","III"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    MSI = structure( c(1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1 ),
      levels = c("MSS","MSI-Hi"),
      class = "factor"
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/blob/master/R/ggforest.R#L81) line does a partial match of "StageII" with "StageIII" on the row names.

```
coef <- structure(list(term = c("GenderMale", "StageIII", "MSIMSI-Hi"
), estimate = c(0.795207848408587, 1.88240540447955, 0.455091789862389
), std.error = c(0.291625356633886, 0.43423050039025, 0.36766034424876
), statistic = c(2.72681311936435, 4.33503727349369, 1.237804938665
), p.value = c(0.00639492461449034, 1.45735426457274e-05, 0.215788396790699
), conf.low = c(0.223632652427522, 1.03132926272586, -0.265509243408779
), conf.high = c(1.36678304438965, 2.73348154623325, 1.17569282313356
)), row.names = c("GenderMale", "StageIII", "MSIMSI-Hi"), class = "data.frame")

inds <- c("GenderFemale", "GenderMale", "StageII", "StageIII", "MSIMSS", "MSIMSI-Hi")

coef[inds, ]
#                  term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value   conf.low conf.high
# NA               <NA>        NA        NA        NA           NA         NA        NA
# GenderMale GenderMale 0.7952078 0.2916254  2.726813 6.394925e-03  0.2236327  1.366783
# StageIII     StageIII 1.8824054 0.4342305  4.335037 1.457354e-05  1.0313293  2.733482
# StageIII.1   StageIII 1.8824054 0.4342305  4.335037 1.457354e-05  1.0313293  2.733482
# NA.1             <NA>        NA        NA        NA           NA         NA        NA
# MSIMSI-Hi   MSIMSI-Hi 0.4550918 0.3676603  1.237805 2.157884e-01 -0.2655092  1.175693
```

This was the intended result

```
#                  term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value   conf.low conf.high
# NA               <NA>        NA        NA        NA           NA         NA        NA
# GenderMale GenderMale 0.7952078 0.2916254  2.726813 6.394925e-03  0.2236327  1.366783
# NA.1             <NA>        NA        NA        NA           NA         NA        NA
# StageIII     StageIII 1.8824054 0.4342305  4.335037 1.457354e-05  1.0313293  2.733482
# NA.2             <NA>        NA        NA        NA           NA         NA        NA
# MSIMSI-Hi   MSIMSI-Hi 0.4550918 0.3676603  1.237805 2.157884e-01 -0.2655092  1.175693
```

Something like this would be better

```
coef[match(inds, rownames(coef)), ]

#                  term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value   conf.low conf.high
# NA               <NA>        NA        NA        NA           NA         NA        NA
# GenderMale GenderMale 0.7952078 0.2916254  2.726813 6.394925e-03  0.2236327  1.366783
# NA.1             <NA>        NA        NA        NA           NA         NA        NA
# StageIII     StageIII 1.8824054 0.4342305  4.335037 1.457354e-05  1.0313293  2.733482
# NA.2             <NA>        NA        NA        NA           NA         NA        NA
# MSIMSI-Hi   MSIMSI-Hi 0.4550918 0.3676603  1.237805 2.157884e-01 -0.2655092  1.175693
```

You could use labels that will not partially match until the bug is fixed, eg, use 2/3 instead of II/III

Comment: wow, I would never find this myself, thank you! 
So, is the bug already reported? I can't find it among the open issues.

Comment: @VasilyA the bug comment was just my opinion, maybe there is another reason that is the expected result. it actually surprised me that the bracket subset would default to partial matching, `$` does partial, but `[[` is exact by default, `[` is different for some reason